# Getting Path of the executable in current folder C++

Tags: c++, winapi, path

I am trying get path of the exe file at the same folder where this program will been. but i couldnt figure out how to do, i did something like this but it only gets the current programs path, and i dont know how to replace filenames between my program and the program i want to get path.

so simply can you help me about get the path of an exe (i know the name of that exe ) at the same  folder where this program will been...

```
    char fullp[MAX_PATH];
    char selfp[MAX_PATH] = "..//myprogram.exe"; 
    char otherprogram[MAX_PATH] = "//test.exe";

    DWORD szPath;
    szPath = GetModuleFileName(NULL, selfp, sizeof(selfp));
```

Comment: If this is Windows specific, add the winapi tag to your question.

Comment: What are the double slashes for?  No OS uses that.

Comment: I am using windows, and i dont know why only " // " works on me... i tested other ones and didint worked

Comment: Please confirm: You have two programs in the same folder. You want to get the location of the first program and use that location to generate the path of the second program.

Comment: Elliot you don't need those '//' anyway. At least not there.

Comment: user4581301 yes i want to modify first programs path, and i want to chance the last part, i mean the name of program.. and with that it will be second programs path.. sorry for bad english

Comment: You are confusing `//` with `​\\​`. You need to say `​\\​` in a C++ string literal because `​\​` is the escape character. You don't need to do that with `/`.

Answer (score 5):

The Win32 API has a whole bunch of [Path Handling functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559.aspx) available.

For instance, once you have obtained the calling process's full path from `GetModuleFileName()`, you can use [`PathRemoveFileSpec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) to remove the filename leaving just the folder path:

```
char selfdir[MAX_PATH] = {0}; 
GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, selfdir, MAX_PATH);
PathRemoveFileSpecA(selfdir);
```

And then use either [`PathAppend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565.aspx) or [`PathCombine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx) to append a different filename to that path:

```
char otherprogram[MAX_PATH] = {0};
lstrcpyA(otherprogram, selfdir);
PathAppendA(otherprogram, "test.exe");
```

```
char otherprogram[MAX_PATH] = {0};
PathCombineA(otherprogram, selfdir, "test.exe");
```

Comment: Being as it is 2016, I am sorely tempted to downvote this otherwise correct answer for the use of ANSI APIs. :-\

Comment: @CodyGray the OP was using Ansi buffers. Since we don't know what the buffers are bring used for, I didn't change them.

Answer (score 0):

OP is most of the way there. Here is an example of how to get the rest of the way.

To simplify the solution, I'm leaving `char` arrays as far behind as possible and using `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char selfp[MAX_PATH];
    std::string otherprogram = "Failed to get path";

    DWORD szPath;
    szPath = GetModuleFileName(NULL, selfp, MAX_PATH);
    if (szPath != 0) // successfully got path of current program
    {
        // helper string to make life much, much easier
        std::string helper = selfp;
        //find last backslash in current program path
        size_t pos = helper.find_last_of( "\\" ); 

        if (pos != std::string::npos) // found last backslash
        {
            // remove everything after last backslash. This should remove 
            // the current program's name.
            otherprogram = helper.substr( 0, pos+1);
            // append new program name
            otherprogram += "test.exe";
        }
    }
    std::cout << otherprogram << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use `std::string`, you might as well go all the way and use the Unicode versions of the Windows API functions with `std::wstring`, `wchar_t`, and `GetModuleFileNameW()`, for maximum effect. Also note Remy's answer below (but mind the minimum OS requirements).

Comment: @and Remy's answer has no minimum OS requirements. Those shlwapi functions have been there since Windows 95. The MSDN documentation means minimum *supported* OS, as in, the minimum OS that Microsoft will provide support for. But yeah, agreed 100% on using Unicode and `std::wstring`.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought Windows 8 introduced a bunch of new path functions? I've forgotten which are which, so it's possible the ones in Remy's answer aren't the new ones and I didn't remember =P

Comment: @and Hmm, I wasn't aware of any new path functions introduced in Win 8, and I don't find anything in a quick search or look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920512.aspx) that seems relevant. I know that Win 10 Anniversary Update removed the MAX_PATH limitation on an opt-in basis, but that's the only recent news I'm aware of on the path front. The functions in Remy's answer are the old standard ones from the shlwapi.h header. Although I might have overstated the case. Lots of them came with IE updates and were not in Win 95 gold. Which ones were you thinking of?

Comment: @CodyGray the `PathAlloc*()`, `PathCch*()` and `PathIsUNCEx()` functions. I knew there was something specific about the new ones; it was the Alloc and Cch features that I was thinking of. Hm, `MAX_PATH` is no longer a limitation for these functions? I wonder what I can use if I want to run on platforms prior to Windows 10, because it's this limit that dissuades me from using those functions :/

Comment: @and You can bypass the MAX_PATH limitations by specifying native NT-style paths, prefixed with \\?\. This is basically an escape that allows you to skip the Win32 filename handling logic, which is limited to MAX_PATH, and pass the path directly to the NTFS subsystem, which allows up to 32k. This works for all versions of NT. Of course, this didn't used to help much for the old shlwapi helpers, but the new functions you've just taught me about alleviate this limitation. The `PathCch*` functions say that they work with \\?\ paths just fine.

Comment: @CodyGray all right then; thanks for clearing that up! (I used a zero width space in one of my comments above to get around backslashes and Markdown.)

Comment: Quite glad I got linked in on this conversation. I don't do much Windows coding and didn't know those suckers existed. Dropping a link to the path Functions page for future reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd807193(v=vs.85).aspx